# Real time tracking with trackpy

Tags: python, image-processing, trackpy

I am trying to implement real time tracking with trackpy. As in grabbing feed from microscope camera and tracking. As of yet i am unable to do this in real-time. trackpy works like a charm when working over a a finite set of images or tiffstack.

Any leads could help.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://github.com/soft-matter/trackpy/blob/a316c658ffd03d4b6fe705b9bedd63c1ab8276c0/trackpy/linking/linking.py#L20-L81 is where I would start.  There is definitely code in there that does linking a frame at a time which means you can feed it with a generator.